# How to strip "garbage" characters without losing valid albeit "weird" characters?

Tags: java, string, text, utf-8, special-characters

I've got a bunch of input data, sometimes I get some garbage characters, example:

> âDots Baby Shower Invitationsâ

Clearly at some point in its past it was `"Dots Baby Shower Invitations"`. But it came to me garbled. I'd be happy to just remove the garbage `â` characters in cases like this.

But my data set is very large, just removing all non english characters might be somewhat **naïve**, as in the case of the word naïve. I wouldn't want `ï` to be removed of course.

So is there a potentially automated solution to this problem? Has anyone come before me with this issue? Is this a case of "computers aren't as smart as humans"?

Comment: Smells like an encoding issue - how is the data coming to you?  It could be getting corrupted upstream, or possibly by your input process assuming everything is iso-8859-1

Comment: You are using the wrong encoding to decode the data, the data itself is most likely fine... can you show your code?

Comment: Encoding issue: yes, within my control: no. The issue occurs upstream of me, and I get this garbage. Like it or not I have it. And although this one source caused issue, many other sources will not and may have valid non-english characters.

Comment: You cannot get any text to your program without decoding first, that's for sure. What makes you so sure you are decoding it correctly on your end?

Comment: I'm looking into this line of reasoning, I'll download the file via the browser and check it to be sure, but I've had so many other mal-formed data issues with this source that I'm highly suspicious that this is the providers issue.

Comment: You just need to look at the raw bytes of the input, although I'm quite sure it is in UTF-8. You need to show your code, so we can help you at the point where encoding needs to be specified. You cannot get text to your program without some kind of decoding being used, if you think so, you are using the platform default encoding implicitly which is hit or miss.

Comment: I'm using the platform default for Java, I will certainly verify. Browsers certainly support UTF-8 and should handle an FTP file transfer without loosing encoding, so I think that's a safe bet. In all likelyhood this is occurring because the upstream provider of the data has this problem, and they're a royal pain to work with to solve it. I need some way to cleanse it in the mean time.

Comment: Clearly, if you don't have a precise definition of what qualifies as garbage, no computer algorithm is going to solve this for you. The best you can get in that case is ultra-sophisticated, borderline-AI, **fallible** heuristic.

Comment: Looks like somebody is pasting from, say, Word.

Comment: No, this is large scale product data coming in from a many source providers, catalogs of data via FTP, one such provider is really really bad at managing their data (this is far from my only correction of their data). Probably dinosaurs working in IT there. It's quite annoying.

Comment: @DavidParks using default encoding is always a bug unless the program only writes and reads files it created itself, in any other case you need to actually find out what encoding the input is using and use the proper encoding to decode it.

Comment: I misstated that, I actually don't do any work with the file in my code, Apache Hadoop does, so I presume it knows what it's doing. But in any case, I've verified the raw file is mal-formed and am trying to get the source to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an english dictionary like [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) and modify only the words that cannot be found in there.
For example *naïve* contains a "strange" character, but is in the dictionary, so it doesn't get changed. *âDots* on the other hand, also contains a strange char, but won't (hopefully) be in the dictionary, so it will be modified and the *â* will be deleted.

This might be too much effort, but as you said you needed a working solution fast maybe it's worth a try... and it will probably work better that a quickly-hacked heuristic!

Comment: Nice thought, from everything so far I see this is a tough problem to solve.